# gmail sign in not support in webview

Tags: android, webview, google-signin

I m trying google sign in in my android app using webview. 
in my site its work properly but same page not work in webview

my webpage is : http://docscanner.co.nf/intex.html

and my androidjava code is

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_main);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webview.requestFocusFromTouch();

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.loadUrl("http://docscanner.co.nf/intex.html");
```

Comment: Is there any error or it just doesn't work. Whats in your logcat

Comment: Miss have You try another site url work ??..

Comment: yes i try other site

Comment: Who said `not support` ? It's not working for you. because you are missing something.

Comment: can u tell me what i m missing

Comment: @AanalShah for using google sign in android using webview is a bad Idea. You should use google play services for using google-sign-in. Google already has a very beautiful getting started guide here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Comment: @AanalShah just put code which i was posted i have check in my emulator.and its work fine

Comment: i needed something else after sign in so that i m using webview @Vipinagrahari

Comment: after sign in what you want to do??

Comment: @AanalShah see my answer bellow...

Comment: after sign in i want to upload pdf to google drive

Comment: It's Better if you do it with `Google Play Services` as @vipinagrahari said. You will get all the idea how to integrate it from Getting Started Guide.

Comment: but i need 5 more integration in my application that why i m using webview  @jaydroider

Comment: @AanalShah what are those 5 other integrations

Comment: everynote, dropbox,onedrive,box,onenote

Comment: @AanalShah Check this link may help you for google sign in with web view https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-oauth2-webview.html

Comment: I found my answer , its work properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/32516119/5898490

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your URL. It is wrong there is spelling mistake.

URL should be this

```
http://docscanner.co.nf/index.html
```

instead of this

```
http://docscanner.co.nf/intex.html
```

Comment: @AanalShah so have you got your solution ??

Comment: [docscanner.co.nf/index.html]  give this type of out put on android webview   [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CyBaKey6y6UXdUNUtNZ3lCTlU/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: and it gives other output on web browser...it shows gmail icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109769/discussion-between-aanal-shah-and-bajirao-shinde).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_main);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.loadUrl("http://docscanner.co.nf/intex.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    String url = "http://docscanner.co.nf/intex.html";
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

        private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code i have check in my emulator and its work well.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView vishalWeb;
    String Cookies;
    boolean RTFA = false;
    boolean FedAuth = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vishalWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);



        vishalWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             //   vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        vishalWeb.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        vishalWeb.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=en&service=mail#identifier");
        vishalWeb.clearCache(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.i("TAG", "url1=>" + url);

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: no i don't want to open gmail only, i configure google sign in with my docscanner  site and its allow user to sign in with gmail

Comment: just replace url with this ==>https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Den%26utm_medium%3Dbutton%26utm_campaign%3Dweb%26utm_content%3Dgotodrive%26usp%3Dgtd%26ltmpl%3Ddrive&urp=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Ftab%3Dgo#identifier

Comment: @AanalShah so you want to directly upload your docs when user sign in ??

Comment: ya i also done its work in website look docscanner.co.nf/index.html

Comment: I have on option for this it when you sign in you get cookies and using that you can fire  on drive to upload docs

Comment: @AanalShah you can make web request to upload docs on drive it provide rest api

Comment: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-apps-and-google-drive-picking-files.html

Comment: `04-21 13:40:37.741  23874-23874/synergy.ashah.myapplication I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/2172305219-idpiframe.js (6)` give this type of error in logcat

Comment: when you get this Error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109774/discussion-between-vishal-halani-and-aanal-shah).