# How to use google sign-in in webview apps?

Tags: android, google-chrome, uiwebview, android-webview, google-signin

**I am trying to make an app of my website with android web view but unfortunately google sign-in is not working on the web view app it is showing this error**

[image]

**Is there any shortcut or trick for this or if there is any other method to use google sign-in in web view apps then please let me know.**
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the only solution I found was the answer by [Risal Shahriar Shefin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14248656/risal-shahriar-shefin) in
[Google sign in not working android webview app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125741/google-sign-in-not-working-android-webview-app), which still works as of today.