# React Native WebView Google signin not working

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I created mobile app using `React-native` and I am loading my `react js website` inside the app using `react-native-webview`. There is google signing option in the website, that is not working in app, It showing `disallowed_useragent`, after that i added `userAgent` in `webview`, still google signing not working, is there any solution for this?

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this doc from Google Dev](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html#instructions-android), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167203/android-google-login-not-working-inside-webview) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125741/google-sign-in-not-working-android-webview-app/32516119)?

Comment: has this been solved?